# Copy UIView frame and transform to a new view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiview

I want to create a copy of a UIView where the frames and the transformation are identical.

How would I do this, to copy the frame and transform from UIView1 and create UIView2 based on this information (I do not have access to UIView1 in the part of the code where UIView2 is being created - data is sent in a serialized format).

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frameYouPassedToYourMethod];
view2.transform = transformYouPassedToYourMethod;
```

Comment: In this case won't frameYouPassedToYourMethod already be the frame which has been modified after e.g. scaling was performed on the original object? If so, then you are performing the transform on it twice (at least the scaling part of it)

Comment: Ah, I see.  Well, to get the pre-transform frame you could save the transform, apply the identity transform, get the frame and then re-apply the original transform.